# Why Angular HttpRequest adding private properties to url?

Tags: angular, typescript

Probably I'm missing something but when I'm trying to make http request this way:

```
protected get<T>(path: string, options?: IOptions, sortOpts?: SortOptions, pageOpts?: PageOptions): Observable<T> {
  if (sortOpts && pageOpts) {
    this.prepareQueryArgs(options.params, sortOpts, pageOpts);
  }
  const opts = { ...this.opts, ...options };
  return this.http.get<T>(`${opts.url}/${path}`, { headers: opts.headers, params: opts.params })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.reportError)
    )
}
```

I'm getting url that contains HttpRequest private properties (private map;
    private encoder;
    private updates;
    private cloneFrom;) - `http://localhost:4200/api/v1/applications?updates=null&cloneFrom=null&encoder=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&map=%5Bobject%20Map%5D&....`

```
export interface IOptions {url?: string, headers?: HttpHeaders, params?: HttpParams, body?: any};
```

[image]

Comment: What about the `prepareQueryArgs` method you've defined in your code? What does it do to the arguments? And I'm pretty sure that you won't be able to access the same instance of the arguments that you've passed to the method. Secondly, what have you defined `this.opts` as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access modifiers don't exist in JavaScript, they're purely a TypeScript construct used by the compiler as a developer aide. All properties will be included as request query params.

```
class A {
    private a: string;
    public b: string;

    constructor(a: string, b: string) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Will be transpiled to

```
class A {
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

You'll want to define a class or interface that contains only the properties you want to turn into query params and map them over. The `params` argument will accept a plain ol' `{ [key: string]: any }` if I remember correctly.